# How to use collec_set in hive to generate 0 for null

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

We have requirement to collect the values for all the different transection and display in "|" delimited and display 0 for the not available merchant.

table_1

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 129867 | paytm | 4 |
| 18945 | paytm | 5 |
| 129867 | payzap | 6 |
| 18945 | payzap | 4 |
| 456312 | paytm | 3 |

[image]

we need to read the table1 and transform it into tabl2 as given below:

table_2

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| 129857 | 4l6 |
| 18945 | 5l4 |
| 456312 | 3l0 |

[image]

suppose we have two merchant i.e paytm and payzap, how to achieve this in hive.

I have tried like:

```
SELECT col1,
       Nvl(Concat_ws('|', Collect_set(col3)), 0) AS col2
FROM   table_1
GROUP  BY col1;
```

but I am not getting desired result.

Answer (score 0):

If you using sql server then use  `string_agg`

```
SELECT col1,
       CASE
         WHEN col2 NOT LIKE '%|%' THEN Concat(col2, '|0')
         ELSE col2
       END AS col2
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               String_agg(col3, '|') col2
        FROM   table
        GROUP  BY col1) B
```

In Hivesql I have provided you with syntax

```
SELECT col1,
       CASE
         WHEN col2 NOT LIKE '%|%' THEN Concat_ws(col2, '|0')
         ELSE col2
       END AS col2
FROM   (SELECT col1,
               Concat_ws('|', Collect_set(col3)) AS col2
        FROM   table_1
        GROUP  BY col1) A
```

Comment: how to set 0 for the merchant which don't have any transection like "456312", as for this there in no transection for merchant "payzap"

Comment: I have changed my answer, Did it worked in your case

Comment: :This will not work as I have given you the two merchant but in real time it is 5 merchant, could you please suggest on it

Comment: what is merchant? I am not good in hivesql